# how could i use @ character as a Rust decorator to implement trait to a struct?

Tags: python, struct, rust, decorator, traits

How could i use decorator with if possible @ character to have python style taste while implementing traits on my structs ?

```
trait Animal {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.name
    }
}

trait Felidae {
    fn to_claw(&self) -> &str;{
        println!("i can scratch off !");
    }
}


struct Dog {
    name: String,
}

struct Cat {
    name: String,
}

@Animal
Dog

@Animal,Felidae
Cat
```

Comment: I don;'t know rust, but this doesn't look like it would be a Python decorator either.

Comment: You can't. The "closest" thing to a decorator is probably to add a custom derive: https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/macros/custom-derive.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How could i use decorator with if possible @ character to have python style taste while implementing traits on my structs ?

Rust is not Python, Rust doesn't use the `@` character or runtime decoration. As zgerd points out you can, however, define [*custom derives*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html#how-to-write-a-custom-derive-macro) which would let you write something like

```rust
#[derive(Animal)]
struct Dog {...}
```

I highly question the value of it in this case as the implementations are not exactly onerous:

```rust
trait Animal {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str;
}
trait Felidae {
    fn to_claw(&self) {
        println!("i can scratch off !");
    }
}

struct Dog {
    name: String,
}
impl Animal for Dog {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str { &self.name }
}

struct Cat {
    name: String,
}
impl Animal for Cat {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str { &self.name }
}
impl Felidae for Cat {}
```

*At most*, for such a simple trait you'd write a basic [declarative macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/appendix-04-macros.html#declarative-macros-with-macro_rules-for-general-metaprogramming):

```rust
macro_rules! animal_impl {
    ($t: ty) => {
        impl Animal for $t {
            fn get_name(&self) -> &str { &self.name }
        }
    }
}
animal_impl!{Dog}
animal_impl!{Cat}
```

[That's what most of the standard library does to reduce boilerplate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops/bit.rs.html#395-430), though I wouldn't even bother unless you need such self-similar implementation on a good half-dozen types or so.

Also note that your `Animal` trait definition is not correct, which simply trying to compile it would have told you (even without implementing it): fields are not a valid concept in traits.

Also this looks like some sort of pseudo-OO hierarchy thing, which is likely a bad idea.

Comment: i am trying to adopt Rust mindset, and i am starting to learn Entity Component System...thank for your answer.